# Сложение 2 чисел типа short в Java

Tags: java

Итак, тип `short` - 16 бит, от -32768 до 32767.

Простой код:

```
short x1 = 5, x2 = 38;
x1 = x1 + x2;
System.out.println(x1);
```

Ругается на ошибку во 2 строке, просит привести к типу `int`:

> Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: possible lossy
>   conversion from int to short

Хотя казалось бы, почему - сложение двух чисел одного типа.

Но такой код, как ни странно, работает без ошибок:

```
short x1 = 5, x2 = 38;
x1 += x2;
System.out.println(x1);
```

> Вывод: 43

Почему?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Любые арифметические операции над типом **short** на выходе дают **int** (результат автоматически кастуется в **int**).
В случае же с `x1 += x2` по факту происходит `x1 = (short) (x1 + x2)`

> При вычислении выражения **(a @ b)** аргументы **a** и **b**
>   преобразуются в числа, имеющие одинаковый тип:
>
> - если одно из чисел **double**, то в **double**
> - иначе, если одно из чисел **float**, то в **float**
> - иначе, если одно из чисел **long**, то в **long**
> - иначе, оба числа преобразуются в **int**
>
> То есть, все целочисленные литералы в выражениях, а так же типы
>   **byte**, **short** и **char** расширяются до **int**.

Answer (score 10):

Согласно спецификации Java SE 8 Edition (15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators)

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = **(T)** ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that
>   E1 is evaluated only once.

то есть имеет место явное приведение типа правого выражения к типу левого выражения

```
E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))
    ^^^^
```

Для вашего примера данное предложение

```
x1 += x2;
```

эквивалентно согласно приведенной цитате следующему предложению

```
x1 = ( short )( x1 + x2 );
```

Для не составного оператора присваивания такого явного приведения типов нет, а потому вы сами должны применять явное приведение типов, если таковое требуется, и в данном примере

```
short x1 = 5, x2 = 38;
x1 = x1 + x2;
```

так как тип выражения `x1 + x2` является `int` а левый операнд имеет тип `short`, то есть имеет место "сужение" значения то следует написать

```
short x1 = 5, x2 = 38;
x1 = ( short )( x1 + x2 );
```

Думаю, что будет важно отметить для расширения кругозора, что тоже самое правило имеет место и в C#. То есть в отношении этой операции Java и C# ведут себя одинаково. Данный код

```
short x1 = 5, x2 = 38;
x1 = x1 + x2;
```

также не будет компилироваться в C#, тогда как данный код

```
short x1 = 5, x2 = 38;
x1 += x2;
```

успешно скомпилируется, так как возможно явное преобразование из типа `int` в тип `short`.